# Putting list into csv

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I have a list in Python 3. I want to split a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] to [1,2,3,4] in one row and [5,6,7,8] the other. I am currently using this to write to CSV however I am doing the split manually and there will be a blank cell after it writes not sure how to get rid of it that's another problem also

```
outfile = open('list.csv','w')
out = csv.writer(outfile)
out.writerows(map(lambda x: [x],list))
outfile.close()
```

Comment: How does `list` look like?

Comment: ['*********',
 <function __main__.Hyperopt_SVM_All(list, max_evals, arrayX_train, arrayy_train, arrayX_test, arrayy_test, n_splits, algoused)>,
 'tpe.suggest',
 'Choice',
 {'C': 4.920379498753717,
  'classifier': 0,
  'degree': 8,
  'gamma': 79.0412142800482,
  'kernel': 1},......] something like this

Comment: Does my answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
outfile = open('list.csv', 'w', newline='')
out = csv.writer(outfile)
out.writerows([list[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(list), 4)])
outfile.close()
```

Or with `with open`:

```
with open('list.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    out = csv.writer(outfile)
    out.writerows([list[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(list), 4)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv 
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout:
    w = csv.writer(fout)
    w.writerow(a[:4])
    w.writerow(a[4:])
```